# Trouble parsing Json into .net Object

Tags: json, parsing

I've studied other questions like this and I'm not doing something right. My vb.net class is wrong or something. Should my class only try to represent from candidates on or what?
I need help with deserializing this json:

```
{
  "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 2286
  },
  "candidates" : [
    {
      "address" : "100 MAIN ST",
      "location" : {
        "x" : 1144782.9490543604,
        "y" : 81361.525678694248
      },
      "score" : 100,
      "attributes" : {

      }
    },
    {
      "address" : "100 E MAIN ST",
      "location" : {
        "x" : 1120908.3257195801,
        "y" : 169917.71846333146
      },
      "score" : 77,
      "attributes" : {

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using the following code to deserialize:

```
Public Shared Function Deserialise(Of T)(ByVal json As String) As T
      Dim obj As T = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

      Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json))
         Dim serializer As DataContractJsonSerializer = New       DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType())
         obj = serializer.ReadObject(ms)
         Return obj
      End Using
   End Function
```

And my vb.net class looks like this:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class SearchResults
   Private mCandidates() As candidate

   <DataContract()> _
   Public Class SpatialReference
      Private mwkId As String


      <DataMember()> _
      Public Property wkid() As String
         Get
            Return mwkId
         End Get
         Set(ByVal value As String)
            mwkId = value
         End Set
      End Property
   End Class

   <DataMember()> _
   Public Property Candidates() As candidate()
      Get
         Return mCandidates
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As candidate())
         mCandidates = value
      End Set
   End Property
End Class

<DataContract()> _
   Public Class candidate
   Private mAddress As String
   Private mLocation As Location
   Private mScore As String
   Private mAttr As String

   <DataMember()> _
Public Property address() As String
      Get
         Return mAddress
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
         mAddress = value
      End Set
   End Property

   <DataMember()> _
   Public Property location() As Location
      Get
         Return mLocation
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Location)
         mLocation = value
      End Set
   End Property

   <DataMember()> _
   Public Property score() As String
      Get
         Return mScore
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
         mScore = value
      End Set
   End Property

   <DataMember()> _
   Public Property attributes() As String
      Get
         Return mAttr
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
         mAttr = value
      End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

Comment: _what_ exactly isn't working?

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm not getting anything into the .net class I built. No errors but no results either.

Comment: I could probably re-write your class to deserialize but im going to say this instead. Get this extension for Visual Studio http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6 It allows you to copy JSON output and right click - paste as class; trust me from someone who spent hours writing these classes, this works!

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it. It's only, seemingly, available for VS 2012 and only will paste if using a C# project but it totally did the trick. It created the JSon classes for me, I pasted those into my vb project (as vb.net of course) and it deserialized it and I got my results. I think my class was correct but the data types were incorrect. Thank you so much for that tip Matt. Yahoo!

Comment: Haha , no problem - it's f0x not Matt! ;) Matt edited your post.

Comment: Doh! Sorry f0x. I blew that. :) It was a great tip nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I dont know .net but i can tell you it related to JAVA. You can relate this with .Net

When we need to serialize or deserialize our class objects to json or from json we need Gson,

In Java we generally import tha package Gson package create its object for example:-

Suppose i have a class User, whose object you wanna serialize. Now to do this

take the whole object covert it to JSON with some key name with the help of Gson

```
jsonObject.put("KEYFORTHISjsonObject", gson.toJson(userClassObject));
```

Now you have serialized it to JSON,
While deserializing it

just create ur User object. Get Json Object from Json file

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFile.toString())
    userObject2 =  gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), User.class);
```

so now userObject2 has all the values that you serialized earlier.

if you are not familiar with JAVA then Read about Gson for .net 
or you can read this link as well http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: The above json is a string returned from a web service call and I need to deserialize it into a .net object. Therefore I created the above class to deserialize it into. That's what I need help with, if possible, assuming my use of the DataContractJsonSerializer is correct.